# Rate limiting calls to a function without an event listener (throttle)

Tags: javascript, rate-limiting, debouncing, google-ad-manager, adx

I have a long infinite scroll page full of videos that I am refreshing a sticky ad on. On each scroll to a new video the URL is updated. Each URL update fires a callback that calls the refresh function. I would like to rate limit how fast the function can be fired so that refresh calls don't happen too fast if the user scrolls too quickly.

I have been able to get throttle working in a test environment while using an event listener for a button click instead of the URL change callback, but have been unable to find a way to make it work without an event listener.

Here's the base code, as you can see I need to rate-limit how fast `refreshFirstSlot` is called.

```
// Function which refreshes the first slot
var refreshFirstSlot = function () {
  googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    googletag.pubads().refresh([adSlot1]);
  });
};
// UrlUpdate is called each time the URL updates
UrlUpdate = function (url, type) {
  refreshFirstSlot();
};
// throttle code
const throttle = (callback, delay) => {
  let throttleTimeout = null;
  let storedEvent = null;
  const throttledEventHandler = (event) => {
    storedEvent = event;
    const shouldHandleEvent = !throttleTimeout;
    if (shouldHandleEvent) {
      callback(storedEvent);
      storedEvent = null;
      throttleTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        throttleTimeout = null;
        if (storedEvent) {
          throttledEventHandler(storedEvent);
        }
      }, delay);
    }
  };
  return throttledEventHandler;
};
// adding the refresh call
var returnedFunction = throttle(function () {
  refreshFirstSlot();
}, 5000);
// final call
UrlUpdate = function (url, type) {
  returnedFunction();
};
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

1. load your page => call your ad
2. scroll your page => refresh your ad unless previous call has not been rendered / ended
3. and so on...

To do so, you can use Google Publisher Tag's events (see [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.events.event)). Here is a simple example :

```
var refreshReady = false;

//slotRequested
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRequested', function(event) {
  var slotId = event.slot.getSlotElementId();
  if(slotId === adSlot1.getSlotElementId()) {
    //every time adSlot1 is requested, we disable the refresh variable
    refreshReady = false;
  }
});

//slotRenderEnded
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
  var slotId = event.slot.getSlotElementId();
  if(slotId === adSlot1.getSlotElementId()) {
    //every time adSlot1 has been rendered, we enable the refresh variable
    refreshReady = true;
  }
});

var refreshFirstSlot = function () {
  if(refreshReady) {
    googletag.cmd.push(function () {
      googletag.pubads().refresh([adSlot1]);
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log('not yet !');
  }
};

UrlUpdate = function (url, type) {
  refreshFirstSlot();
};
```

You could add a timeout to make sure the ad is not refreshed as soon as rendered (improve viewability)